# renaming files; wildcard selects input, want to return wildcard value in output

Tags: bash, windows, variable, wildcards

I have a set of files as follows:

```
Q-30-09-1753.TIF
W-01-04-1753.TIF
W-31-12-1752.TIF
Y-14-12-1752.TIF
```

Using **git bash on Windows** I wish to rename the files to put the letter at the end of the filename as follows;

```
30-09-1753-Q.TIF
01-04-1753-W.TIF
31-12-1752-W.TIF
14-12-1752-Y.TIF
```

I have attempted to use the following code:

```
for f in *.TIF ; do 
    mv "$f" "${f//[A-Z]]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[A-Z]/}";
    echo "$f"
done
```

The first part successfully selects the files to change but the wildcard selection is literal when renaming them.

Comment: "I'm using git bash": Does that perhaps mean you're on Windows? This would be very important information because filename handling is different. +

Comment: Hi Marcus, yes I'm on Windows at work.  Thanks for pointing that out that issue, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably be lazy and let `sed` do this for me

```bash
newfilename=$(echo "${f}"|sed 's/\(.\)-\([^\.]*\)\.TIF/\2-\1.TIF/')
mv "${f}" "${newfilename}"
```

instead of learning the probably excellent, yet separate string replacement methods of bash :)

By the way, if these are dates, your date format is bad for sorting. Be more ISO date format instead: YYYY-MM-DD will allow you to sort your file names according to the date correctly! (Otherwise you'll sort by day-of-month first, then month second, and year last.)

```bash
newfilename=$(echo "${f}"|sed 's/\(.\)-\(..\)-\(..\)-\(....\)\.TIF/\4-\3-\2-\1.TIF/')
```

Comment: I'm probably being very dense but if I save that as newfilename.sh and then try to run it;

with bash I get "mv: cannot stat '': No such file or directory"

with sed I get "sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command"

Comment: it's not meant to be run as script on its own – it goes inside your `for`/`done`, replacing the `mv` there! Otherwise, the `f` variable isn't set.

Comment: I tried, and it works for me with your filenames! Can you tell us what `sed --version` says?

Comment: that works now, thanks Marcus!